# Form breaks down after opening

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I can't understand why my win Form hangs when the infinite while starts. how can i fix this? when there's no while it seems to work. I've tried doing it with events but and without invokes but i get "accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on". I have no idea what else can i try because I'm trying to seperate the UI from the logic.

```
 public GroupChatForm(string username)
        {
            gchat = new GroupChat(username);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GroupChat_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listMessage.Text = gchat.Start();
            Thread ctThread = new Thread(postMessage);
            ctThread.Start();
        }
        private void postMessage()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                    this.Invoke(new Action(postMessage));
                else //listMessage.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => listMessage.Text = listMessage.Text + gchat.getMessage()));
                    listMessage.Text = listMessage.Text + gchat.getMessage();
            }
        }
```

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace StudentForYouGroupChat
{

    public class GroupChat
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient();
        NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);
        string readData = null;
        string message;
        string username;

        public GroupChat(string username)
        {
            this.username = username;
        }
        public string Start()
        {
            readData = "Conected to Chat Server ...";
            clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + "$");
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();
            /*Thread ctThread = new Thread(getMessage);
            ctThread.Start();*/
            return msg();
        }
        public void Send(string msg)
        {
            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg + "$");
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();
        }
        public string getMessage()
        {
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            var buffSize = 0;
            byte[] inStream = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
            buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
            serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
            var returnData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
            readData = "" + returnData;
            return msg();
        }
        //Laikinai pasalinsime ir uzdesime be if'o

        public string msg() 
        {
            /*if (this.InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(msg));
            return "error";*/
            //else
            return Environment.NewLine + " >> " + readData;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try moving `gchat = new GroupChat(username)` after `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: First, you're completely ignoring the **return value** of [Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read?view=netframework-4.8), which tells you how much data in your receive buffer is actually valid.  You pass that information along to GetString() so you get a valid string back (instead of possible garbage).  See the example in the link...

Comment: Second, yes, you should be using **EVENTS** for this.  Make your GroupChat class contain the thread and the while loop.  When you have an actual message, then you raise that event.  It would be the job of the **FORM** to marshal that event back to the UI thread when it receives the event.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I still get the "accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on" Error, how should invoke so it would still work?

Answer (score -1):

> @Idle_Mind I still get the "accessed from a thread other than the
>   thread it was created on" Error, how should invoke so it would still
>   work?

Not sure what you've tried...here's a "simplified" version of what I'm talking about:

```
public class GroupChatForm : Form
{

    public void foo()
    {
        GroupChat gc = new GroupChat();
        gc.MessageReceived += Gc_MessageReceived; // wire up the event
        gc.Start();
    }

    private void Gc_MessageReceived(string message)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                Gc_MessageReceived(message); // recursive call that will become UI safe on the second call
            }));
        }
        else
        {

            // ... it's safe to update your GUI in here with "message" ...

        }
    }

}

public class GroupChat
{

    public delegate void dlgMessage(String message);
    public event dlgMessage MessageReceived;

    public void Start()
    {
        // setup your TCP stuff
        // start a new thread that has MessageLoop() below in it
    }

    public void MessageLoop() // ... running in a new THREAD ...
    {
        String message;
        bool newMessageReceived = false;
        while (true)
        {

            // ... blocking code that receives a message ...

            message = "some message from the stream";
            newMessageReceived = true;

            if (newMessageReceived)
            {
                // raise the event w/ the message
                MessageReceived?.Invoke(message);
                newMessageReceived = false;
            }
        }

    }

}
```